# Como reparar una url presignada de una pagina ajena?

Tags: javascript, java, html, nodejs

Trabajo en una red **crowdsourcing**, y en un trabajo asignado donde deberia haber 5 oraciones provenientes de esta url:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/lpds.share.f8/ecd238209dcc27e180cfb8e7d70b937259047ec36f7c9c9c8bc822fe0b06be13.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJISLNG3LFA6MKL3A%2F20181220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181220T225906Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=905f7542ac5851d4cb967d9bec0c451aae26c7fb2b15bbad84c09f651ae42598`

Solo me da el siguiente error:

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Request has expired</Message><X-Amz-Expires>604800</X-Amz-Expires><Expires>2018-12-27T22:59:06Z</Expires><ServerTime>2020-01-09T14:51:33Z</ServerTime><RequestId>C8016059FAA26763</RequestId><HostId>SWu2MOcs7qq4vW4HXUhzbGL9c/gAN7RScH7ThbmXwV5lciaispb7nspixxYG8hhVFe0gPSpE1tk=</HostId></Error>`

Veo que la fecha del enlace expiro, pero como podria repararlo desde mi lugar?. Lei algo como web scraping o cosas asi.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Realmente pareciera que te está diciendo que la firma -signature- o la credencial expiraron, por lo que te niega el acceso. Creería que esos valores son dinámicos y deben renovarse de alguna forma.

Comment: Hay poco o nada que puedes hacer, el propietario del archivo en AWS debe prefirmar otra url y compartirlo o hacer su bucket público para que no sea necesaria una url prefirmada, si la url fue generada automaticamente tendrías que hacer el análisis de la página que la genera.